# Find the range of the function $f(x) = \frac{2 + \sin x}{3 + \cos x}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Find the range of the function $$f(x) = \frac{2 + \sin x}{3 + \cos x}.$$

Honestly, I'm completely stumped. This is a pre-calculus course. We haven't learned derivatives and we are not allowed to use a calculator. I understand the range to be the distance between the minimum and maximum of the function. Theoretically I was supposing it might be like tangent with a range of $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. I know a sine curve's range is $[-1, 1]$ as is cosine, but I do not know what to do about combining them. My teacher is of very little use and gives us questions beyond what he's taught.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382136/a-problem-on-range-of-a-trigonometric-function-what-is-the-range-of-frac-sqr/382153#382153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need calculus to find the range.

Write $$y=\frac{2+\sin x}{3+\cos x}$$ and rearrange as $$\sin x-y\cos x=3y-2$$

Use a compound angle transformation to rewrite the left hand side as $$\sqrt{1+y^2}\sin(x+\alpha)$$

Knowing the range of $\sin$ enables us to write $$\left|\frac{3y-2}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right|\leq 1$$

Squaring this and rearranging leads to $$8y^2-12y+3\leq0$$

So we end up with the range which is $$\frac 14(3-\sqrt{3})\leq y\leq \frac 14(3+\sqrt{3})$$

Comment: This Desmos graph gives some graphical evidence the above calculations are correct: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zfr0ydylxp

Comment: Can you explain "Use a compound angle transformation to rewrite the left hand side as" this step to me? How did you transform first equation?

Comment: @NikaChelidze Let $$\sin x-y\cos x=R\sin(x+\alpha)$$ and get $R$ in terms of $y$